# Symbol for clover with four leaves

Tags: symbols

Is there a way in Latex to get a symbol representing a four-leaf clover ? In other words, I am looking for an equivalent of `\clubsuit` but with four leaves.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! You have `bbding` with `\FourClowerOpen` and  `FourClowerSolid`; The  `niceframetype1` provides the type 1 versions of this font and a few others.

Comment: If you can use Unicode fonts (and xelatex/lualatex), there is  U+1F340 in Unicode, for example, in the `Noto Emoji` font. Each font will implement the drawing differently; for example, in `EmojiOne Color` font, the drawing is an outline (open).

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, the [`bbding`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/bbding) package provides two four-leaf clover symbols. Another option from the [`twemojis`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/twemojis) package is provided as well.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bbding,twemojis}

\begin{document}

\texttt{bbding}:

\begin{tabular}{rl}
\verb|\FourClowerOpen| & \FourClowerOpen \\
\verb|\FourClowerSolid| & \FourClowerSolid
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\texttt{twemojis}:

\begin{tabular}{rl}
\verb|\twemoji{four leaf clover}| & \twemoji{four leaf clover}
\end{tabular}
 
\end{document}
```

[image: clovers]